# spring mvc requestmapping issues

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

i'm working in a spring mvc app (im new in spring mvc).

this is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/prueba2")
public class controller2 {

Stock stock=new Stock();
List stockList=new ArrayList<Stock>();
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/BeanLocations.xml");
StockBo stockBo = (StockBo)appContext.getBean("stockBo");


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Stock returnCustomer(ModelMap model) {
    stock=stockBo.findByStockCode("7668");
    model.addAttribute("miStock", stock);
    return stock;


}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Stock>returnAll(ModelMap model) {

    stockList=stockBo.findAll();
    System.out.println("lista objetos--->"+stockList.toString());
    model.addAttribute("listaStock", stockList);
    return stockList;


}

public StockBo getStockBo() {
    return stockBo;
}

public void setStockBo(StockBo stockBo) {
    this.stockBo = stockBo;
}
}
```

this is my view:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Message : "Por fin funciona!!!"</h1>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Codigo Stock</th>
<th>Nombre Stock</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>${miStock.stockCode}</td>
<td>${miStock.stockName}</td>
</tr>

</table>




<h1>Tabla con lista de stock</h1>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <th>Codigo Stock</th>
            <th>Nombre Stock</th>

        </tr>

            <c:forEach items="${listaStock}" var="stock">
        <tr>
            <td>
                ${stock.stockCode}
            </td>
            <td>
                ${stock.stockName}
            </td>

         </tr>

        </c:forEach>

    </table>

  <ul>codigo stock
   <c:forEach items="${listaStock}" var="stock">
  <li> <c:out value="${stock.stockCode}"></c:out>  </li>
    </c:forEach>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

what i want to do is to show 2 tables in the same JSP, i dont want to go to a different page to show each table, but i dont understand very well how to use the "requestmapping" to make it work.. now is just showing me the first table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need access to the stock list as well as the individual stock item in the same JSP, then just add the stock list to the model.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Stock returnCustomer(ModelMap model) {
    stock = stockBo.findByStockCode("7668");
    model.addAttribute("miStock", stock);
    model.addAttribute("listaStock", stockBo.findAll()); // Add the list to model
    return stock;
}
```

Alternatively you can set it as a separate method which will save on duplication if it's used in many methods within the same controller.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Stock returnCustomer(ModelMap model) {
    stock = stockBo.findByStockCode("7668");
    model.addAttribute("miStock", stock);
    return stock;
}

@ModelAttribute("listaStock") 
public List<Stock> getAllStock() { // Called and set by Spring automatically
    return stockBo.findAll();
}
```